# Is putting a ElastiCache behind a microservice worth it in the following scenario?

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-elasticache

I have a bunch of EC2 processing an object (let's assume the objects are unique URLs of images that needs to be downloaded from the web). I have 3 Elasticache dbs: all three dbs track different thing about images. I need to consult the 3 databases before deciding whether to process the image or discard it.

I need to decide whether each EC2 instance should consult with the 3 dbs on their own, or whether I should encapsulate the 3 dbs behind a microservice such that each EC2 does not communicate directly with dbs.

Having a microservice and using API to communicate obviously adds processing time overhead but generally while scaling it is worth it. But ElastiCache is a fast in-memory db service, and I cannot decide whether the overhead is worth it. What should I do? Or, what should I look into before deciding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microservices architecture is a nice thing but it comes with a big price: you will have one more distributed moving part in your system.

If you need to:

- deploy separately this new microservice,
- you want to be able to use whatever programming language you want for this,
- you need to scale separately this functionality (you can still scale the `Elasticache`, separately, without a microservice) or
- you need to be able to change from `Elasticache` to another cache,

then YES, do extract it to a microservice otherwise NO, don't, just extract it to a module inside the monolith.

Comment: That's a nice way to think about it. I looked up more on this issue, and I think the answer for my case is NO